# ANTLRWorks generates Parser declaring throws but nothing else in java file

Tags: java, antlr, antlrworks

I just started looking into `ANTLR`, and noticed `ANTLRWorks 1.5` generates the Java parser file, but with incomplete throws declaration.

**Grammar file:**

```
grammar ASTDemo;

options { 
  output=AST; 
}

parse
    :   orexpr+
    |   andexpr+
    |   TAG ' ' parens
    |   TAG (parens andexpr)+
    |   together+
    ;

parens
    :   '(' TAG ')';

andexpr
    :   TAG (AND^ TAG)+;    

orexpr
    :   '[' TAG (OR^ TAG)+ ']';

together
    :   TAG (' '^ TAG)*
    ;

TAG     : ('FOO' | 'BAR');
OR  :   '|';
AND :   ': ';
WS  :   (' ')+;
```

Here is the sample line that has the incomplete throws statement

```
public final ASTDemoParser.parse_return parse() throws  {
```

The current version of JDK being used to launch `ANTLRWorks` is 1.6x
Has anyone seen this before?

The unfortunate part, with this compile error `ANTLRWorks` is not allowing me to Debug my grammar within it. I'm forced to manually fix the file each time I want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just compiled your grammar using `ANTLRWorks 1.5 rc1` and `JDK 1.7.0.11`.

All compiled well, and mentioned code line looks like:

`public final ASTDemoParser.parse_return parse() throws RecognitionException {`

It could be arbitrary bug manifestation. Try to recompile it again, and may be you have try to use `JDK 1.7`.

Comment: Having ANTLRWorks launch using JDK 1.7x did resolve the problem. Thanks! Now to try and figure out why the Debugging won't work. There's always something. :) Thanks again!!

Comment: I'm getting this with AntlrWorks 1.5 and JDK 1.7u21 , too. AntlrWorks1.4.3 works fine.